# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity`

Tags: magento2, product

when i try to add new product i get this error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)??? from where it comes and how to fix it please

Comment: Did you disable any core Magento modules?

Comment: no i just installed this extension  https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form

Comment: and when i tried to add attributes i get this error also i can add product to cart but in same time the cart is empty what 's going on

Comment: try to disable this extension to see if it is it what's causing problems.

Comment: i disable it but still facing problems :'(

Comment: i tried with an old version before installing this extension and i still having this SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Hi @Developper Magento, did you find any solution to this problem?